Shouldn't "wear off" be followed by the preposition "from" or "off" in "When the new wore off his grandfather’s watch"?
This context comes from the book "To Kill A Mocking Bird" by Harper Lee.
"“Oh, no sir!” Jem pulled out his grandfather’s watch that Atticus let him carry
once a week if Jem were careful with it. On the days he carried the watch, Jem
walked on eggs. “Atticus, if it’s all right with you, I’d rather have this one instead.
Maybe I can fix it.”
When the new wore off his grandfather’s watch, and carrying it became a day’s
burdensome task, Jem no longer felt the necessity of ascertaining the hour every
five minutes."
If "wore off" is a phrasal verb which means...

To be gradually removed by long or hard use, attrition, or exposure: So many people touched the picture that its luster finally wore off. (American Heritage Dictionary)

...why isn't it phrased "When the new wore off from his grandfather's watch..."?
I know that "of" is sometimes omitted in phrasal verbs ending in "off" (though it's retained when "off" is followed by a pronoun), but in this case shouldn't the preposition "from" and not "of" be used? "The paint came off from the wall" and not "The paint came off of the wall"? Or maybe "of" means the same thing as "from"? I can't find much evidence for it although "from" could be substituted for "of" in these sample sentences in this definition:
"of" (preposition)
5. used to indicate separation, as in time or space: within a mile of the town; within ten minutes of the beginning of the concert.
(Collins English Dictionary).

It’s the same reason we can speak of, say leaving the office, and don’t have to say leaving from the office. (Indeed, those two expressions would typically be understood to mean different things.)

No, x wears off [noun]. The make-up paint wore off his face. The writing wore off the sign. The writing wore off the rocks.  That sentence from Harper Lee is fine. the phrasal verb wear off does not take from. "The smile wore off his face as he became increasingly agitated". :) wear off=fade

@Paul Tanenbaum "living from the office" would mean that someone is living his job?

Why must we repeat ourselves? I don't get it. Truly.

@StaticBounce, note that I used leaving, not living.

@Paul Tanenbaum I meant leaving too.

Ok, I see it. The phrasal verb "wear off" does not take "from". But I'm still wondering. Can the preposition "of" carry the same meaning as "from" sometimes?

Here’s the difference. Leave the office means simply go out of or away from the office. By contrast, if, say, someone were going on a business trip and said, “I'm leaving from the office,” that would mean they were heading from the office directly without stopping at home on the way for example.

The writer is using the "uneducated, dialectal" style of her characters. At the very least, new should be newness, but idiomatically even that would be below par compared to When the novelty wore off. This certainly isn't a suitable text for anyone wanting to learn current idiomatic English - it's "quaint, interesting, literary" text for native Anglophones.

Yes, "wear off from" can apply in some cases. Here, there is nothing physical to get thinner and go anywhere. The fresh feeling wore gradually away ... in feeling.

The (optional) preposition for the cited context is usually of, not from.

@FumbleFingers Do you agree that it is incorrect to use "of" after "off" when they are not followed by a pronoun? Is this a rule?

@StaticBounce: No! It's not a "rule"! Like I said, we usually use of in such contexts, but that certainly doesn't mean from is invalid. Also note that in the cited context (the [novelty] wore off his grandfather’s watch) we wouldn't normally add any other preposition after off, but syntactically it would be fine to include either of OR from there.

These are all idiomatic:

The sandy desert winds wore off the shed's paint.
The sandy desert winds wore the paint off the shed.
Why is the shed so dilapidated? --The sandy winds wore the paint off.
Why is the shed so dilapidated? --I guess the paint just wore off.
The paint wore off the shed exposed to constant sandy winds.
You'll see. The fake gold plating will wear off of that trophy in no time.
Time had worn the gilt paint from the book's spine.

